# How to run HTML5 on eclipse ADT to create Android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, html

I have Android Developer Tool Build: v22.3.0-887826 This product includes Eclipse Platform, JDT, CDT, EMF, GEF and WTP and I want to program HTML5 to create  Android application on this version of eclipse , is that possible? , I mean to run HTML5 on ECLIPSE?

Comment: I use [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) and when I write my programs for Android then I can run them on Desktop and HTML5 right from Eclipse... just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (and don't) run HTML5 on Eclipse.

It is possible to create android application with HTML5 though.  There are several ways of doing it.  You can find literally *TONS* of information by searching google for [html5 android app development](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=html5+android+app+development&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gl=uk) - you'll find everything you need.  Spend some time researching this - and you'll get to the answer.

One of the most common frameworks is [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) - again, spend some time researching - you'll get to the answer.

Comment: When I right click on my HTML project in eclipse I right click and press run as web application. It uses Google GWT, isn't this HTML5?

Comment: thanks , so u recommend other tools than eclipse , I found phonegap , OK thanks will look more

Comment: @user26442 Eclipse is a tool; you'll need another tool to help with packaging HTML5 app into an android app.